# What are possible reasons for the " warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI' " with Git under windows

Tags: git, windows-10, git-credential-manager

My `Git version is 2.39.0` (the recent one) under windows 10. I got the

```
warning: could not find UI helper 'GitHub.UI' when trying to 
clone a rep on github.
```

1. What are possible causes of this error?
2. And how to fix it?

Reinstalling Git, rebooting. Still the same error.

Comment: How exactly did you try to clone a repository on GitHub?

Comment: How are you running Git? Are you using the CLI in Git Bash, or some other interface? Also, how did you install Git? There are multiple possible answers to this question, so knowing which one you used will be important to answer your question.

Comment: I installed the package available for windows 64x, so in git bash I type 'git clone URL'

Comment: git clone https://github.com/The-Software-Guild/sre-git-refresh   .
Maybe the repository setting are not permitting it to be cloned??

Comment: This warning comes from [git-credential-manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager), not from Git itself. It looks like a recent release may be missing some parts, given that you and someone else asked very similar questions at almost the same time.

Comment: I can confirm this issue happens to me too, after upgrading to the newest git version today.